# Constraining Pulp Binary Variable Selection Based on Another Variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm creating an optimisation script for Fantasy Football. It starts off quite easily- loading in players & their relevant details.

The key in this game is that 15 players can be selected in your squad but only 11 can be fielded per week.

What I would like to do is have 2 variables- one defining that the player is in your squad and a sub-variable that determines whether you put the player in your starting 11.

I have tried a few things- one broad solution is that have 2 unrelated variables. 1 that selects 11 starters and a second that selects 4 subs. This works well for 1 week, but for example one week Player A from your squad might be best starting and the next he's better on the bench. Therefore I would get a more optimal solution if I can make the starting 11 variable a subset of the squad variable.

I've attached the code defining the variables and my attempt at creating a constraint that would link them together. (there are other constraints that all successfully work. For example I can pick a starting 11 or a squad of 15 to maximize expected results without issue, but I cannot pick a starting 11 within a squad of 15.

```
#VECTORS OF BINARY DECISIONS VARIABLES
squad_variables = []
for rownum in ID:
    variable = str('x' + str(rownum))
    variable = pulp.LpVariable(str(variable), lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat= 'Integer') 
    squad_variables.append(variable)

xi_variables = []
for rownum in ID:
    bariable = str('y' + str(rownum))
    bariable = pulp.LpVariable(str(bariable), lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat= 'Integer') 
    xi_variables.append(bariable)
```

The code below is not working for this task and is the root of the problem..

```
#ID CONSTRAINTS (ie. only 15 unique id selection across both systems)
id_usage = ""
for rownum in ID:
    for i, player in enumerate(squad_variables):
        if rownum == i:
            formula = max(1*xi_variables[rownum],(1*player))
            id_usage += formula
prob += (id_usage ==15)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated- perhaps this is simply a non-linear problem. Thank you :)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you are asking here. Can you be explicit about the actual question you would like an answer to? Also, it's not clear what you mean by a variable being "a subset of" another variable -- variables are not sets. Finally, please use Markdown to typeset your code as code so it's easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a constraint that says "if `x[i] = 0` then `y[i] = 0`". The typical way to do this is through the constraint `y[i] <= x[i]`. Note that this only works if both variables are binary; otherwise a modified approach is necessary. I can't quite follow your `PuLP` code so I won't try to give you the code for this constraint, but I assume you'll be able to implement it once you understand the logic.

Comment: Happy to help. Don’t forget you can mark the answer as accepted when you’re ready to. Also feel free to join us over on the [Operations Research Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top) — launching soon!